# Is the matrix multiplication possible with template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Let me define a matrix class as follows

```
template<typename T, size_t rowSize, size_t colSize>
class Matrix
{
 //Class implementation
};
```

Now if i've 2 matrices defined as

```
Matrix<double,3,2> A;
Matrix<double,2,5> B;
A*B;
```

Can the multiplication be done, If I try it would say no arguments can take the rhs as double,2,5 for *. Is it possible to generalise the template to multiply       'double,x,y' and 'double,y,z' and return a new matrix 'double,x,y'

Comment: Overload the * symbol. Your function prototype something like: Matrix operator*(Matrix A, Matrix B)

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to overload with different parameters, is it something like template<size_t b >Matrix<T, rowSize,b>& operator*(const Matrix<T, colSize, b> &obj)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename T, size_t rowSize, size_t colSize>
class Matrix
{
    // Implementation
};

template<
    typename T,
    typename U,
    size_t rowSize1,
    size_t commonSize,
    size_t colSize2
>
auto operator * (Matrix<T, rowSize1,commonSize> const & a,
                 Matrix<U, commonSize,colSize2> const & b)
  -> Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>()), rowSize1, colSize2>
{
    // Implementation
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<double,3,2> A;
    Matrix<double,2,5> B;
    auto C = A*B;
}
```

Or as member:

```
template<typename T, size_t rowSize, size_t colSize>
class Matrix
{
public:
    template<typename U, size_t colSize2>
    auto operator * (Matrix<U, colSize,colSize2> const & b)
      -> Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T>()*std::declval<U>()), rowSize, colSize2>
    {
        // Implementation
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying this within the matrix class, which already has a 
template<typename T, size_t rowSize, size_t colSize>. Is it not possible to do that way?

Comment: @user3345850 Sure.  It would be something like `template<typename U, size_t otherColSize> auto operator*(Matrix<U, colSize, otherColSize> const& other) { ... }`.  That declaration looks a bit awkward though, because of the use of `colSize` as `other`'s `rowSize`.

Comment: A 2 argument friend declaration similar to the member `*` is a 3rd option.  Also note that matrices benefit hugely from expression templates.

Comment: Could you please give me an idea, how the same can be implemented without returning auto (like in old c++03)? Just matter of curiosity.

Answer (score -1):

It is possiple to overwrite the `*` operator within a class. 
But then it would be generally

```
    T& T::operator*(T otherMatrix);
    {
      //do multiplication by hand and return a new Matrix
    }
```

and not taking just `double` as only type.

Comment: well I'm sorry, but I'm not asking about the overloading function

Comment: if you asked for the type checking, maybe you could use the `typeid()`function: